# CRUD Firebase para objeto Java

Tags: java, firebase

Me enfrento a un problema creando el CRUD para un objeto Java en Firebase, en la documentación no hay ninguna sección al respecto.

Suponiendo que el CRUD es sobre `User.java`:

```
public class User {

    private int birthYear;
    private String fullName;

    public User(String fullName, int birthYear) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }
    public long getBirthYear() {
        return birthYear;
    }
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
}
```

Como se implementaria este interfaz?:

```
public interface UsersRepository {

   public void createUser(User user);
   public User readUser(String fullName);
   public List<User> retrieveAllUsers();
   public void updateUser(User user);
   public void deleteUser(String fullName);
}
```

Comment: Mirate ese blog, implementa CRUD usando Firebase http://shrikanthkr.github.io/android/2015/09/09/firebase-crud-android.html

Answer (score 1):

En la documentación de Firebase se encuentran las respuestas a tus dudas, para persistencia de datos [Saving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html) y para obtenerlos datos [Retreiving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html)

Comment: La documentación es obsoleta hoy en dia.